# Google plus API: How to check if user is sharing URL page?

Tags: api, url, search, stream, google-plus

Is it possible to find out, whether visitor of my website is sharing some particular URL on his Google plus stream?
Could I get this information using PHP or Javascript?

EDIT: 
I mean sharing URL using share link 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink
 not sharing after clicking on +1 button.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of, but not guaranteed because the post would need to be shared publicly and the effort to find it is not efficient and would require possibly many API calls and parsing on your side.

Depending on what you have in mind there might be a policy issue to consider if you are using one of the +1 or share buttons:

The [Google+ policies](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy) state

> Publishers may not attempt to discover the identity of a Google+ button user unless the user consents to share his or her identity with the Publisher via a Google-approved authorization procedure. This prohibition includes identifying users by correlating Google+ button reporting data from Google with Publisher data.

So, you will need to get consent to access the APIs to identify them via the OAuth 2.0 scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`, which will allow you access to their basic profile data. After that, the most efficient approach likely would **not** be using the  [`activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) method to get all their public posts, but instead to use the [`activities.search`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) method to search for the given URL in public posts, then you'd parse the response to see if the current user's ID matches one of the shares. If your site is really popular, you'd likely need to page through many responses, which wouldn't be the most efficient.